# how to extract a property value from a object sender?

Tags: c#, object

Two different slider controls fires this function below, their names are seektomediaposition and seektomediaposition2.

```
public void seektomediaposition_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {

string name = Convert.ToString(e.Source.GetType().GetProperty("Name"));//wont return what i need.
MessageBox.Show(name);
if(name=="seektomediaposition")
  // whatever is the code
if(name=="seektomediaposition2")
  // whatever is the code

    }
```

e.Source.GetType() would return the type Slider.

e.Source.GetType().GetProperty("Name") would return "Name" instead of "seektomediaposition" or whatever the controls name who raised the event to this function.

How can i get the name displayed on that messagebox so i can take my decision based on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GetProperty() returns a PropertyInfo object. With that you can call GetValue(e.Source, null).

```
public void seektomediaposition_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {

string name = Convert.ToString(e.Source.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(e.Source, null));
MessageBox.Show(name);
if(name=="seektomediaposition")
  // whatever is the code
if(name=="seektomediaposition2")
  // whatever is the code

    }
```

Comment: _PropertyInfo t1 = e.Source.GetType().GetProperty("Value"); t1.GetValue(e.Source, null) you're right with that i can access any property, i just find out that what i really need it was the Value and not the name. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Your Function "seektomediaposition_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs e)" has an object sender.

so here you can say
    if (sender == seektomediaposition)
      do this
    else if (sender == seektomediaposition2)
      do other thing

Comment: This is a better solution than mine if you know in advance what the sliders will be. If instead you need to get the name of potentially any slider added to the page that would trigger this event, you would need something more like my solution.

Comment: I've tried that after you post but a got an error. couldn't convert double to object. maybe i didn't understand the idea completely, i still would have to apply Tom's answer to this kind of comparison if it was the case. thanks anyway, problem is solved.